# Only the first upload directory shows in assets when used with wygwam

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, wygwam

When using the main assets window, all of the available upload directories are available to choose from in the left hand navigation. (See Screenshot 1)

When using the popup generated by wygwam when adding a link or inserting an image only the first upload directory defined is available (See screenshot 2)

Is it possible to list all upload directories in the wygwam popup?

Thanks,

Colin

[image]

[image: Wygwam popup]

Comment: Does your Wygwam config (Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config name]) have a specific Assets source selected? Leave the "Upload Directory" setting blank if you want to show all of them.

Comment: Yes it did, That's sorted it.
Thanks!

Comment: Glad that fixed it! :) Just posted it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config name], and set the “Upload Directory” setting to blank, and Wygwam will start showing all of your upload directories.